Cannot CTRL+C in VSCode bash terminal to kill terminal
I cannot kill terminal in bash VS code using WSL debian when running npm run dev. Meanwhile at command prompt it work normally, I think it is a VS Code Issue.
How can I solve this problem?
I have tried this at keybindings.json but still won't solve the problem.
Does anyone know how I can make Ctrl + C work in the VS Code terminal on WSL Debian?
Any help would be appreciated.
